# why python quitting unexpectedly while trying to import something

Tags: python, python-2.7

sometimes when I try to import some module or package my python quits unexpectedly ,

like not I tried `import ansi2html` and i got the below error and kicked out from python shell
with segmentation fault: 11
[image: python quits unexpectedly]

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does the application work when launched from the terminal? That said, this is a segfault from `readline` - it seems like something is trying to read from the terminal, but a GUI app wouldn't have one attached.

Comment: yes.. i usually get this error when i try to import in python shell..

i also discovered that my pkg_resources has gone missing could it be the reason ?

Comment: @millimoose As I know, GUI app has no terminal input only on Windows.

Comment: i think pkg_resources is the cause of problem, I have installed distribute to get pkg_resources but i am still getting the error

Comment: @akaRem The readline library *might* be doing something else than just reading from stdin to support hotkeys and such. Anyway, it was just a guess based on the stack trace.